# Build a list using specific keys in a dict (python)?

Tags: python, list, search, dictionary, dijkstra

I'm implementing the Dijkstra search algorithm in Python. At the end of the search, I reconstruct the shortest path using a predecessor map, starting with the destination node's predecessor. For example:

```
path = []
path.append(destination)
previous = predecessor_map[destination]
while previous != origin:
    path.append(previous)
    previous = predecessor_map[previous]
```

Is there any way to do this with less lines of code (e.g. list comprehension)?

Comment: This is perfectly clear as it is.  Don't ruin it by trying to make it a one liner.  I suppose you could make an iterator that yields each predecessor and use a list comprehension on that, but that just hides the logic.

Comment: You don't really have a list to iterate over in a comprehension, so I'm guessing no. Your code is straightforward as it is, anything you're likely to accomplish will be pure code golf.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only suggestion that I have is to get rid of the slight code duplication:

```
path = []
previous = destination
while previous != origin:
    path.append(previous)
    previous = predecessor_map[previous]
```

Beyond that, I think your code is actually very clear and is unlikely to benefit from any attempts to shorten it.

Lastly, it is worth noting that the above also works when `destination == origin`, whereas your original version most probably doesn't (depends on how exactly `predecessor_map` is populated). Don't know if this is relevant to your use cases.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Thanks. I've already updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: This differs from the original code, notice that in the original the returned list has *at least* one element, the destination

Comment: @ÓscarLópez: See the last paragraph of my answer.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez: Rethink your downvote.  The original code would try to look up the predecessor of the origin in the case that `origin == destination`, which would probably raise a `KeyError`.  The difference to the original code is not a bug, it's a bugfix!

Answer (score 4):

This might work:

```
path = [destination]
path += iter(lambda: predecessor_map[path[-1]], origin)
```

It behaves the same as your original code. But what you've already written is fine as is.

If `destination` could be equal to `origin`:

```
path = []
path += iter(lambda: predecessor_map[path[-1]] if path else destination, origin)
```

It behaves the same as [@aix's code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7741662/build-a-list-using-specific-keys-in-a-dict-python/7741801#7741801).

Comment: Fine except that you can't `+=` an `iter()` to a `list`. But if you use `path.extend()`, it should work.

Comment: @glglgl You can `+=` an `iter()` to a `list`. That code works.

Comment: Oops, I was not aware of that. I thought about the behaviour of `[] + ()` - quite inconsistent...

Answer (score 3):

```
def backwalk(mymap, start, origin):
    yield start
    current = mymap[start]
    while current != origin:
        yield current
        current = mymap[current]

path = list(backwalk(predecessor_map, destination, origin))
```

This separates the walking and collecting tasks.

If you can ensure that you never start with the origin, you can simplify to

```
def backwalk(mymap, start, origin):
    current = start
    while current != origin:
        yield current
        current = mymap[current]
```

Comment: If I was reading the code I would understand the original version more quickly than this one.

Comment: Not particularly shorter, but an iterator would be a better API for clients in a hypothetical reusable graph class.

Answer (score 1):

You can recursively traverse the edges assuming `predecessor_map` is a `dict` mapping node to parent node and that `None` is the root:

```
predecessor_map={0: None, 1: None, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 0, 5: 1}
```

Define a recursive function that traverses the tree in reverse:

```
def path(node, predecessors):
    return [None] if node is None else [node] + path(predecessors.get(node), predecessors)
```

Or, if you dare, a Y combinator:

```
Y=lambda f: (lambda x: f(lambda *args: x(x)(*args)))(lambda x: f(lambda *args: x(x)(*args)))
path=Y(lambda f: lambda node, p: [None] if node is None else [node] + f(p.get(node), p))
```

In use (using list comprehension):

```
>>> print [node for node in path(None, predecessor_map)]
[None]
>>> print [node for node in path(0, predecessor_map)]
[0, None]
>>> print [node for node in path(1, predecessor_map)]
[1, None]
>>> print [node for node in path(2, predecessor_map)]
[2, 1, None]
>>> print [node for node in path(3, predecessor_map)]
[3, 1, None]
>>> print [node for node in path(4, predecessor_map)]
[4, 0, None]
>>> print [node for node in path(5, predecessor_map)]
[5, 1, None]
```

Answer (score 1):

One more possible solution is to use functional style programming with deferred output:

```
from itertools import tee, chain, imap, takewhile

predecessor_map = {2:1, 3:2}
destination = 3
origin = 1

def backwalk(predecessor_map, start, origin):

    def deffered_output():
        for i in output:
            yield i

    result, a = tee(deffered_output())
    b = imap(predecessor_map.get,a)
    output = takewhile(lambda x: x!=origin,chain([start],b))

    return result

print(list(backwalk(predecessor_map,destination,origin)))
```

I personally wouldn't use this approach. But it's interesting for training though.

**Explanation**
The key element is `deferred_output` which postpones the calls to `output`.
Then we split `output` into 2 iterators using `tee`.
Then we apply `predecessor_map.get` to the second iterator called `a` and assign the new iterator to `b`.
Then we control the output with `takewhile` and stop when `origin` is reached.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this iteration with a comprehension. Maybe you could simplify it a little, like this:

```
    path, previous = [], destination
    while True:
        path.append(previous)
        previous = predecessor_map[previous]
        if previous == origin:
            break
```

The above loop would look nicer with a do..while , but Python lacks it